# Refresh page if type-error comes in browser's console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issue with a software suite while using ajax data-table (because of cache). Its giving Type-error if I'm opening second ajax data-table after opening first. But when I refresh the page, table shows up so what's I'm thinking is to reload the page if browser's console gives type-error. Any way of achieving so ?

This is the error coming in chrome's console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
at Fa (<anonymous>:62:438)
at ha (<anonymous>:48:389)
at e (<anonymous>:93:32)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:93:118)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.n [as dataTable] (<anonymous>:83:199)
at n.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (<anonymous>:165:488)
at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at setup (form.min.js?ver=1534756250.0:2691), <anonymous>:52:25)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
```

In Firefox, I'm getting

```
TypeError: m[n] is undefined
```

or

```
TypeError: c is undefined
```

I didn't used c or m[n] anywhere throughout the code but I'm calling js libraries for datatable. And because of cache issue I am getting this.

Comment: use location.reload() when error come... :)

Comment: That is what I'm asking actually. How to trigger it only if typeerror comes in console ?

Comment: To trap errors use a `try`/`catch` block, but note that it would be a much better idea spend time fixing the error properly. Refreshing the page to fix an error is a band-aid solution which would not be workable for a production environment.

Comment: Modified my post. Please have a look now

Comment: it will be good if you post the part of the code where the error originate

Comment: Actually the code is working fine if its loaded for the first time or on refresh (ie data-table) its because of cache if i load second page's data-table and then come back and opens first page's data-table, then it is not loading but giving type-error in console and as i refresh the page again the first page's datatable works and second page's give error . SO its kinda loop that only one datatable's page is loading at a time untill refreshed